# Creating a method in prototype and calling it in Init

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a module that I export and call from another file. My code is currently structured as it is below. When I call it from my main file, I get an error saying that my function, doSomething, does not exist. Is there a way to make this work? Should I be structuring my file differently or creating the instance of my object in the main file?

```
module.exports = function(){
    var my_class = function(a){
        this.init(a);
    }

    my_class.prototype = {
         doSomething: (g) => {
             // Doing something here
         }
         init: (b) () => {
              doSomething();
         }
    }

    return new my_class();
}
```

Comment: `doSomething` is a property of the instance, not a standalone function. To reference the instance, use `this`, but to use `this`, you need a full-fledged `function`, not an arrow function

Comment: Huge! Thank you!